# useDapp's useContractCall throws "Invalid contract call" in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

in **React** component I want to read function "paused" in contract deployed on **Rinkeby** testnet. Using **useDapp** (https://usedapp.io/) hook "**useContractCall**", i call contract function in custom hook:

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { useContractCall } from "@usedapp/core";
import { contractAddress } from '../../index.js'

const iface = new ethers.Interface([
  "function paused()"
]);

export function usePaused() {
  const [paused] = useContractCall({
    abi: iface,
    address: contractAddress,
    method: 'paused',
    args: [],
  }) ?? [];
  return paused;
}
```

It throws an error `TypeError: ethers__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.ethers.utils.Interface is not a constructor`

When instead of

```
const iface = new ethers.Interface([
  "function paused()"
]);
```

I use `const iface = new ethers.Interface(abi);`, my custom hook still doesn't work, it throws warning:

```
Invalid contract call: address=0x...contract_address... method=paused args= 
    at RenderButton (http://localhost:3001/static/js/main.chunk.js:1961:70)
```

What am i doing wrong? I followed instructions on https://usedapp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#custom-hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem.

In my case, the react Webapp is set to the Mainnet, but the browser wallet is on Rinkeby.
After the wallet network was changed to the Mainnet, the problem was solved.